# AngularJS form submission

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ng-submit

I've got a form to collect signup details from a user, defined as such:

```
<form class="m-t-xl" ng-submit="signup(user)" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="" ng-model="user.name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" ng-model="user.email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" required="" ng-model="user.company">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" ng-model="user.password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox i-checks"><label> <input type="checkbox"><i></i> Agree the terms and policy </label></div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Register</button>

            <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Already have an account?</small></p>
            <a ui-sref="login" class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block">Login</a>
</form>
```

For some reason, when I click the submission button, nothing happens. The button is just dead.
My controller has the following code:

```
.controller('registerCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Registration', 
                            function($state, $scope, Registration) {

    $scope.user = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        company: '',
        password: ''
    };
    console.log('controller getting loaded');
    $scope.signup = function(user) {
        console.log('register getting called');
    }
}]);
```

It acts as if the form doesn't recognise the "signup" method. In a similar fashion, I implemented a login form with:

```
<form class="m-t" ng-submit="login(credentials)" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" ng-model="credentials.email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" ng-model="credentials.password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>

            <a ui-sref="forgot_password"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
            <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Do not have an account?</small></p>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" ui-sref="register">Create an account</a>
</form>
```

and:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', 'Authentication', 'AUTH_EVENTS', 
                        function($scope, $rootScope, $state, Authentication, AUTH_EVENTS) {

    $scope.credentials = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    };

    $scope.login = function(credentials) {
        Authentication.login(credentials).then(function(user) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
            $scope.setCurrentUser(user);
            $state.go('events');
        }, function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
        });
    }
}]);
```

The second form is working just as intended... I am at a loss as to what is going on. I would like to say that I logged the **registerCtrl** and it is getting loaded properly into the page, however the method doesn't do anything when called.

Any ideas to what else might cause this? I checked all the solutions already on SO but nothing seemed to help.

In my config.js, both routes are similarly declared:

```
.state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "views/login.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Login', specialClass: 'gray-bg' }
        })
        .state('register', {
            url: "/register",
            templateUrl: "views/register.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Register', specialClass: 'gray-bg' }
        })
```

I also tried changing my form to have a ng-click on the "Register" button that calls the same method, but this had the same behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check your console for errors? Are you sure that the right `$scope` is used for the signup form?

Comment: There are no errors. I also checked to see whether "user" was in scope, and adding {{ user }} as debugging text shows the correct text as I fill the forms in. So the "user" variable is synchronized just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "registerCtrl" controller you have $scope and $state mixed:

```
.controller('registerCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Registration', 
                        function($state, $scope, Registration) {}]);
```

It should be:

```
.controller('registerCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Registration', 
                        function($scope, $state, Registration) {}]);
```

I think the problem is you are assigning user object and login function to the wrong application object.

Comment: Wow... I actually had no idea order mattered on DI. Thanks man... saved me a lot of headaches.